# How do I change a value gradually over time?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm using Unity3D 5-point-something, and I'm planning on making a game where the player travels through a hot, dry desert, and so the heat causes the player's energy to deplete.  The object of the game is to reach a certain point before the player's stamina runs out.

What I was planning on doing is having different landmarks in the game world that the player can visit, and these will help replenish their Health or Stamina.

Answer (score 7):

Having a value deplete over time can be done a few different ways. The simplest is likely using the update method to deplete at a constant rate.

```
public float myValue = 10; // the total
public float subractPerSecond = 1; // remove this every second

public void Update() {
    //subtract at a constant rate
    myValue -= subtractPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

But we can make it a bit more robust than that, to allow for change in either direction and to keep the value within specified bounds:

```
public float maxMyValue = 10;
public float minMyValue = 0;
public float myValue = 10; // the total
public float changePerSecond = -1; // modify the total, every second

public void Update()
{
    //modify at a constant rate, keep within bounds
    myValue = Mathf.Clamp(myValue + changePerSecond * Time.deltaTime, minMyValue, maxMyValue);
}
```

We can also calculate the rate automatically by telling the system how long you want it to last total.

```
public float maxMyValue = 10;
public float minMyValue = 0;
public float myValue = 10; // the total
float changePerSecond; // modify the total, every second
public float timeToChange = 15; // the total time myValue will take to go from max to min

public void Start()
{
    changePerSecond = (minMyValue - maxMyValue) / timeToChange;
}

public void Update()
{
    // modify at a constant rate, keep within bounds
    myValue = Mathf.Clamp(myValue + changePerSecond * Time.deltaTime, minMyValue, maxMyValue);
}
```

For your use case, you might also want to subtract based on movement.

```
public float maxMyValue = 10;
public float minMyValue = 0;
public float myValue = 10;
public float decreasePerUnit; //subtract this from the total, every unit moved
float lastXPosition; //keep the last X position to know how far we travel per frame

public void Start()
{
    lastXPosition = this.transform.position.x;
}

public void Update()
{
    //first find the distance we traveled on the X axis
    float thisXPosition = this.transform.position.x;
    float distanceTraveled = Mathf.Abs(thisXPosition - lastXPosition);
    lastXPosition = thisXPosition;

    //subtract distance traveled times the decrease per unit and keep the value >= 0
    myValue = Mathf.Clamp(myValue - (distanceTraveled * decreasePerUnit), minMyValue, maxMyValue);
}
```

When you get to the point where you want to refill, I'd just turn the above value to a positive value and slowly fill up. Or you can simply add a specific amount to the value.